# How to get a specific value from a JSON file

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm Trying to get the "5. adjusted close" data from this json file for each of the time periods.

```json
{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2024-02-22",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Monthly Adjusted Time Series": {
        "2024-02-22": {
            "1. open": "183.6300",
            "2. high": "188.9500",
            "3. low": "178.7500",
            "4. close": "184.2100",
            "5. adjusted close": "184.2100",
            "6. volume": "67308725",
            "7. dividend amount": "1.6600"
        },
        "2024-01-31": {
            "1. open": "162.8300",
            "2. high": "196.9000",
            "3. low": "157.8850",
            "4. close": "183.6600",
            "5. adjusted close": "182.0211",
            "6. volume": "128121557",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        }}}
```

I get the json file and store it as "data". I was hoping this would work but doesn't

```py
r = requests.get(url2)
data = r.json()

for entry in data["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"]:
    print(entry["5. adjusted close"])
```

Comment: `entry` is one of the YYYY-MM-DD strings, not a dict itself.

Comment: This is why we ask for [mcve], so we can direct you to the obvious cause of the problem in the error message you see.

Answer (score 1):

You say you have a JSON file. In which case:

```
import json

with open("foo.json") as data:
    d = json.load(data)
    for v in d["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"].values():
        print(v["5. adjusted close"])
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's find out what an `entry` is in your case:

```py
for entry in data["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"]:
    print(entry)
```

Output:

```
2024-02-22
2024-01-31
```

So, entry is just strings, which is the key part. What you want is the values part:

```py
for entry in data["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"].values():
    print(entry["5. adjusted close"])
```

Output:

```
184.2100
182.0211
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

json_string = '''{
    "Meta Data": {
        "1. Information": "Monthly Adjusted Prices and Volumes",
        "2. Symbol": "IBM",
        "3. Last Refreshed": "2024-02-22",
        "4. Time Zone": "US/Eastern"
    },
    "Monthly Adjusted Time Series": {
        "2024-02-22": {
            "1. open": "183.6300",
            "2. high": "188.9500",
            "3. low": "178.7500",
            "4. close": "184.2100",
            "5. adjusted close": "184.2100",
            "6. volume": "67308725",
            "7. dividend amount": "1.6600"
        },
        "2024-01-31": {
            "1. open": "162.8300",
            "2. high": "196.9000",
            "3. low": "157.8850",
            "4. close": "183.6600",
            "5. adjusted close": "182.0211",
            "6. volume": "128121557",
            "7. dividend amount": "0.0000"
        }
    }
}'''

data = json.loads(json_string)
monthly_adj_close = {date: data['Monthly Adjusted Time Series'][date]['5. adjusted close'] for date in data['Monthly Adjusted Time Series']}
print(monthly_adj_close)
```

Comment: this will provide u the output as.    {'2024-02-22': '184.2100', '2024-01-31': '182.0211'}

Comment: Please format your code properly and read the OP carefully to understand what the inputs and required outputs are

Answer (score 0):

```
for date, values in data["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"].items():
    adjusted_close = values["5. adjusted close"]
    print(f"For {date}, adjusted close: {adjusted_close}")
```

Answer (score -1):

Did you want to loop over the values? When you loop over a dict, it only gives the keys

```
>>> for _, entry in data["Monthly Adjusted Time Series"].items():
...     print(entry["5. adjusted close"])
...
184.2100
182.0211
```